# Как получить дату (Московское время) и сравнить её со строкой yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: java, дата

Есть строка:

```
String dateFromServer = "2015-12-16";
```

Как правильно получить объект `Date` (по Москве) и сравнить его с этой строкой (раньше/позже)?

Comment: (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateFromServer)).after(new Date()) Так?

Comment: А привести обе строки к виду "20151215" и сравнить как числа - плохо?

Comment: Наверное да, придётся тогда прсить строку в число, а это больше операций и менее очевидно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Наиболее удобный способ работы с датами в Java (как минимум до Java 8) - использование библиотеки JodaTime.

Все сведется к тому, чтобы преобразовать строку в локальную дату [`LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) (т.е. дату без привязки к часовому поясу) и получить локальную дату по Москве. А потом сравнить их:

```
String dateFromServer = "2015-12-16";
LocalDate serverDate = LocalDate.parse(dateFromServer);
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Moscow"));

System.out.println(localDate.compareTo(serverDate));
```

---

Для Java 8+ код будет очень похожим на JodaTime:

```
String dateFromServer = "2015-12-16";
LocalDate serverDate = LocalDate.parse(dateFromServer);
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Moscow"));

System.out.println(localDate.compareTo(serverDate));
```

Comment: Библиотека весит 3Мб. Вес приложения менее 2Мб. Вопрос - стоит ли?

Comment: @Checkist стоит переходить на java8

Comment: @Chekist, `joda-time-2.9.1.jar` - 616 KiB

Answer (score 3):

Конкретно в вашем случае:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = sdf.parse("2015-12-16");
```

+ обработка ошибки
и далее сравнение через compareTo или after/before

Comment: Не хватает момента про московскую зону

Comment: Во Владивостоке даст не тот результат, что хочет ТС.

Answer (score 2):

Получение `Date`:

```
String dateFromServer = "2015-12-16";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = sdf.parse(dateFromServer);
```

Сравнение c текущей датой:

```
Date curDate = new Date();
if(curDate.getTime() > date.getTime()){
    //Время с сервара уже прошло
} else {
    //Время с сервера еще не наступило
}
```

UDP момент с временем по Москве:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
Date curDate = calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: Не хватает момента про московскую зону

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а разве она не получается по текущей локале?

Comment: Ну, как верно @Nofate заметил, на ДВ и в МСК `new Date()` выдаст разные результаты. Так что надо вручную зону применить, если время нужно конкретного часового пояса внезависимости от пояса девайса

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну это как бы и логично, тут либо текущую дату приводить к мск, либо мск к текущему поясу...как по мне жители дв хотят жить по своему времени))

Comment: Это-то да, я просто придираюсь к формально заявленному в вопросе)

Comment: А еще вы сравниваете время, а в вопросе речь про дату )

Comment: @Nofate все все все, отступаю и ни на что не претендую)))

Comment: Я просто клоню к тому, что работа с датами и временем да еще и с часовыми поясами - очень тонкая вещь, и писать ее вручную средствами Calendar - верный путь к трудноуловимым багам.

Comment: @Nofate да, с этим полностью согласен, две самые нелюбимые вещи это операции с датой и десятичными числами %)